# VBA コンパイルエラー:メソッドまたはデータメンバーが見つかりません　解決法

Tags: vba, excel

**前提・実現したいこと**
エクセルのVBAとOutlookを連携させて一括送信メーラーを創っています。
指南サイトの手順通りに実装した所、以下のエラーメッセージが発生しました。

**発生している問題・エラーメッセージ**
コンパイルエラー: メソッドまたはデータメンバーが見つかりません

**該当のソースコード**

```
Sub SendEmail()

Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim i
Dim rowMax As Long
Dim wsList As Worksheet
Dim wsMail As Worksheet
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem

Set objOutlook = New Outlook.Application
Set wsList = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("送信先")
Set wsMail = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("メール内容")

With wsList

    '送信先の件数
    rowMax = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    '送信先の件数分繰り返す
    For i = 2 To rowMax
        Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        With wsMail
            .To = wsList.Cells(i, 4).Value       'メール宛先
            .Subject = .Range("B1").Value        'メール件名
            .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain          'メールの形式
            .Body = wsList.Cells(i, 1).Value & vbCrLf & _
                         wsList.Cells(i, 2).Value & " " & _
                         wsList.Cells(i, 3).Value & " 様" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                        .Range("B2").Value              'メール本文

           objMail.Send
        End With
    Next i

    Set objOutlook = Nothing
    MsgBox "送信完了"

End With

End Sub
```

**試したこと**
Google検索をして、単なるスペルミスなのか、iの4のセルが原因なのかと考えましたが、わかりませんでした。
もしおわかりになれば考え方やヒントをご教授願います。

**補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）**
Windows 10
Excel 2019

Comment: `With`を入れ子にして、内側の`With`で外側の`Excel`の`.Range()`を使っているからでは？ 外側の`With`は使う必要が無さそうだし、内側でも素直に`wsList.Range()`を使ってみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: Kunifさん　回答ありがとうございます。おっしゃる通り、.Range()をwsMail.Range()と変更し、色々調整した所正常に動作しました。ご協力ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `With`を入れ子にして、内側の`With`で外側のExcelの`.Range()`を使っているからでは？ 外側の`With`は使う必要が無さそうだし、内側でも素直に`wsList.Range()`を使ってみてはどうでしょう？

Kunifさん　[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/65392/vba-%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%91%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A1%E3%82%BD%E3%83%83%E3%83%89%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9F%E3%81%AF%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%83%A1%E3%83%B3%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%81%8C%E8%A6%8B%E3%81%A4%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93-%E8%A7%A3%E6%B1%BA%E6%B3%95/65579#comment71673_65392)ありがとうございます。おっしゃる通り、`.Range()`を`wsMail.Range()`と変更し、色々調整した所正常に動作しました。ご協力ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

With wsMailの内側で

```
.TO = 
.Subject = 
.BodyFormat = 
.Body =
```

としていますが、これだと

```
wsMail.TO = 
wsMail.Subject = 
wsMail.BodyFormat = 
wsMail.Body =
```

と解釈されてしまいます。本来は

```
objMail.TO = 
objMail.Subject = 
objMail.BodyFormat = 
objMail.Body =
```

がやりたかったことではないでしょうか？

Comment: 堀越保徳さん　返信ありがとうございます。

その通りです。
該当箇所にobjMailを追加し、他にも少々調整したところ、現在、正常に動作しております。

VBAの勉強になり、助かりました。ご回答ありがとうございました！